# Was the main story arc of 1899 completed in the season it had?

Tags: production, 1899

I really enjoyed *Dark*. *1899* is by the same creators, Jantje Friese and Baran bo Odar. Unfortunately, it was cancelled after just a single season.

Is there any sense of completion in that single season, or were most of the story arcs and most importantly the main one, left completely unfinished? In other words, is there any sense in watching it?